# Nexus: Given a pom, only bring in dependent libraries to nexus repo. How?

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a pom.xml for my project - which uses springboot and some other dependencies. in my experimental local-network-nexus-repo LNNP, I want to bring in only those dependencies that are in pom.xml from maven central.

Later, I will point my project to use LNNP.

**How to do that here?**

**Larger point of only making available the dependencies in a list/file/pom:**

The enterprise-infra, or enterprise-architect team must be able to gatekeep at this LNNP level to restrict what libraries, what version gets used, or does not get used in the enterprise [not related to bugs or scanning, just restrict certain libraries, so the unnoffical-use bubbles up to architecture team, and gets not/approved].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Repository managers like Nexus and Artifactory do two (kind of separate) things:

1. They are a repository to upload *your* dependencies to. These are dependencies that aren't readily available on the Internet (they may be truly yours, or they may be JAR files you procured elsewhere and that are also not available on the Internet for whatever reason, like them being proprietary).
2. Serve as a proxy and cache for dependencies that are also available on the Internet. Spring Boot and its dependencies are a good example of such. You could thus point Maven to your repository manager instance. The repository manager would download from the Internet whatever it doesn't have in its cache yet, then serve it to you. Next time a local Maven on your network asks for the same artifacts, the repository manager will serve it from its cache directly.

When your local Maven receives artifacts from the repository manager, it doesn't see a whole lot of difference anymore between 1. and 2. But on the repository manager these artifacts are stored in different containers ("repositories"). The cached artifacts are probably less critical (like in terms of creating backups) and can be repopulated from the Internet at any time, while for *your* dependencies this repository manager is likely the global source of truth (e.g. you may want to make sure there is backups).

So, to answer your questions:

> I want to bring in only those dependencies that are in pom.xml

That's what the proxy and cache function will do for you.

> Later, I will point my project to use LNNP.

Probably you want to point to your repository manager (LNNP) **now**, not later.

Comment: I was thinking, the proxy/cache must also be configured as gatekeeper, not the case?  In an enterprise environment, the architecture and security teams may want to review the dependencies. (1) If a dependency is not EA-approved, alternative is suggested (2) If a dependency is not security-approved, alternative suggested. Development team makes tthe fixes, and provides a new pom.xml, at that point missing/approved libraries are proxy/cached, given a pom.xml. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that Artifactory has features for this, particularly when plugging into their [X-Ray](https://jfrog.com/xray/) tool. It seems [Nexus Firewall](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-firewall) is a similar offering. This stuff may not be cheap, but you said _enterprise_ so that might not be a problem.

Comment: A bit tangential, but I don't believe the items are scanned until the build/until used (then blocked/flagged).  So someone can contribute whatever pom they want.  It's just text, I don't believe either tool mentioned here is forward scanning to that level.  I could be wrong tho.